# How to calculate the maximum load that a standalone PV system can handle?

Tags: solar-cell, inverter, matlab, simulink, mppt

I have a 6820W pv panel, a boost converter, a H-bridge inverter, a 48V 540Ah LI-ion battery, a 100ohm dc and a 100ohm ac load in my system. My question is what is the maximum load that this system can handle while being at Maximum power point(mpp).

[image]

I have asked same question earlier, but my bad i haven't provided much information from myside, please excuse this community members.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve. If the battery can be discarged at 10C, that's 5400 A at 48 V or about 250 kW - think of a Tesla car. Is that enough? All the while, the solar panel would be at MPPT if the controller is working.

Comment: @tomnexus I Think I got the battery capacity wrong. Can one assume a suitable number for this setup and try to calculate the maximum load?

Comment: Look at the datasheet for your standalone solar inverter. It's probably the limiting factor for how much battery output can be sent to the load. Then add in the PV power (less inverter losses), which is probably way less than 6.82 kW depending on season and time of day, and you'll have your answer.