# How to asses the performance of an MPPT algorithm?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, matlab, mppt

I have a standalone pv system with PV Panel rating 6820W, a buck converter, 12V battery , DC resistance (load) of 8 ohm with Perturb and observe (P&O) as the control algorithm.

Upon simulating, the input side power stays around 6750-6815 W but output power stays around 5400W which is 79% of 6820W maximum power point. BUT input power is in 98.5% of MPP. So, what is the efficiency/performance of the algorithm? is it 79% or the latter?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616662/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-load-that-a-standalone-pv-system-can-handle

Comment: Efficiency of the algorithm, or efficiency of the converter? Seems like the algorithm is tracking MPPT pretty well, but the converter is losing power.

Comment: @user253751 i need efficiency of algorithm. So is the efficiency of algorithm determined by the input power from the pv which is 98% ?

Comment: I would say so. This is a simulation, so I guess somewhere in the simulation, converter efficiency is set to be 80%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the maximum load that a standalone PV system can handle?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616662/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-load-that-a-standalone-pv-system-can-handle)

Comment: @user_1818839 This is a different question about the same project.