# How to calculate efficiency of an MPPT Algorithm

Tags: dc-dc-converter, matlab, mppt, algorithm

My PV system with an MPPT algorithm is extracting about 97% power of the Maximum power that can be extracted from the panel. However, the matching of the load through converter did not happen as planned and only 75% of the power is delivered to the load. So, if someone asks what is the efficiency of your algorithm, should I say its 97%? But the MPPT tracker system overall has only an efficiency of 75%?

Comment: More detail would help. What was planned and how does it differ? Is your converter boost or buck (more usual), what are the vin an Vout and current and what converter efficiency did you expect (and why)? How do you know theoretical and actual panel outputs (measured, specifications, ...,) ? Have you allowed for panel temperature? ...

Comment: .... what is the storage system? Batteries? That's probably where the missing 24% is going

Comment: Where is the missing 22% going?

Comment: very very similar: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616858/how-to-asses-the-performance-of-an-mppt-algorithm Are the two of you going to the same class?